# Safari with VoiceOver dropping messages from live region updates

Tags: safari, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers, aria-live

Running Mojave. I have a webpage, that wants to announce something to the user. I found that when it happens, VoiceOver is stuck explaining where the focus is and "forgets" to announce the live region update.

We also noticed this not working on Mojave, but working better on High Sierra.

Thoughts on why that's the case, or what we can do to effectively use the live region without timeouts?

Our workaround is to set a timeout to update the live region where it is likely to not have any distractions, but this feels hacky and not following what I learned an assertive or polite live region should do.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing any code. Have you made sure that the live region is present on page load, and then you add text to it later when you want it announced?

Comment: It seems that changes in focus always preampt aria-live updates, regardless of it being polite or assertive. Generally this prioritization makes sense. I have also observed this on iOS. Sadly, sorry, no answer.